# What is Vac(peak) in this question?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, rectifier, power-engineering, thyristor

Bit confused at what Vm/Vac(peak) is. Either 230V or 325V. rest seems simple

[image: query]

[image: equation utilised]

Comment: It's the constant in front of the sine function. When someone writes Vac, they need to define their meaning. It might mean Vac rms. In which case you have your answer -- apply sqrt(2), appropriately. Since this is an SCR and not a TRIAC, I take it that the angle is relative to the start of the sine and that it turns off at the following zero-cross. Is that right? Anyway, why not show your solution treating it as a variable, for now?

Comment: im not sure if it is rms or peak the Vac. hence my query. vac(peak) = vac x root2 i imagine. unless its just 230

Answer (score 1):

Given that 230V RMS is common in Europe, and the question refers to "AC supply" making me think of domestic mains, I'm sure that \$v_{AC}\$ is the RMS value of 230V, where peaks would be ±325V.

The question is poor, and should really be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

AC supply values, both voltages and currents, are routinely given as RMS values so you'll need to convert 230 Vrms to its peak value (325 V, as you noted). (230 Vrms is the nominal supply voltage in the EU.)

Assuming this is coursework you should show that calculation in your answer so the person marking it can see what you have done.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the average current trough the resistor is given by:

$$\overline{\text{I}}_\text{R}:=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int\limits_0^\text{T}\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

Now, we know that Ohm's law is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)}{\text{R}}\tag2$$

Assuming that the thyristor is ideal (so there is no voltage drop across it, the trigger angle is \$0^\circ\$ and when the input voltage is negative the thyristor is off), we can assume that:

$$\text{V}_{\text{R}\space|\space\text{ideal thyristor}}\left(t\right)=\max\left(0,\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(2\pi\text{f} t\right)\right)\tag3$$

We know that the thyristor is triggered at an angle of \$\alpha^\circ\$, so the voltage across the resistor in your case is equal to:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)&=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if }0\le t<\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}\\
\\
\text{V}_{\text{R}\space|\space\text{ideal thyristor}}\left(t\right)&\space\text{if }\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}\le t<\frac{1}{\text{f}}
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if }0\le t<\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}\\
\\
\max\left(0,\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(2\pi\text{f} t\right)\right)&\space\text{if }\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}\le t<\frac{1}{\text{f}}
\end{cases}
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}

With \$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t+\text{nT}\right)\$ where \$\text{T}=\frac{1}{\text{f}}\$ is the period time and \$\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}\$.

So, now we can find the average current trough the resistor:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\overline{\text{I}}_\text{R}&=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int\limits_0^\text{T}\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int\limits_0^\text{T}\frac{\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)}{\text{R}}\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{f}}}\int\limits_0^\frac{1}{\text{f}}\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\text{f}}{\text{R}}\int\limits_0^\frac{1}{\text{f}}\max\left(0,\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(2\pi\text{f} t\right)\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\text{f}}{\text{R}}\int\limits_\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}^\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(2\pi\text{f} t\right)\space\text{d}t\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{f}}{\text{R}}\cdot\left[-\frac{\cos\left(2\pi\text{f} t\right)}{2\pi\text{f}}\right]_\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}^\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\text{f}}{2\pi\text{fR}}\cdot\left[\cos\left(2\pi\text{f} t\right)\right]_\frac{1}{2\text{f}}^\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{2\pi\text{R}}\cdot\left(\cos\left(2\pi\text{f}\cdot\frac{\alpha}{360\text{f}}\right)-\cos\left(2\pi\text{f}\cdot\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{2\pi\text{R}}\cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi\alpha}{360}\right)-\cos\left(\pi\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{2\pi\text{R}}\cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha\pi}{180}\right)+1\right)\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha\pi}{360}\right)}{\text{R}\pi}
\end{split}\tag5
\end{equation}

---

Now, applying this to your problem we get:

- When \$\hat{\text{u}}=230\sqrt{2}\space\text{V}\$ is the amplitude of the source:
  $$\overline{\text{I}}_{500}=\displaystyle\frac{230\sqrt{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{65\pi}{360}\right)}{500\pi}=\frac{23\left(1+\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{36}\right)\right)}{50\sqrt{2}\pi}\approx0.147293\space\text{A}\tag6$$
- When \$\hat{\text{u}}=230\space\text{V}\$ is the amplitude of the source:
  $$\overline{\text{I}}_{500}=\displaystyle\frac{230\cos^2\left(\frac{65\pi}{360}\right)}{500\pi}=\frac{23\cos^2\left(\frac{13\pi}{72}\right)}{50\pi}\approx0.104152\space\text{A}\tag7$$

Comment: Can the downvote be explained, please?